# Correct origin header for cross-domain ajax request

Tags: python, apache, flask, cross-domain

I have two domains, one is for front-end(abc.aa.com) another is for back-end(xx.abc.aa.com).

I have to upload a picture from the front-end to back-end with ajax only if I set it.

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" to .htaccess`, it will succeed.

Otherwise a cross-domain error will happen, but I want to allow only the abc.aa.com to access this source; how can I achieve this?

I also tried [this tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/56/), but only `origin="*"` will work.

My env:

- python 2.7
- flask
- webuploader

Comment: Could you please use the editing features of stackoverflow and remove the typo in the header?

Comment: sorry, i will pay attention next time,